# svnant status returning wrong results

Tags: svn, version-control, ant, subclipse, svnant

I am using [svnant](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html) and using the [status](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#status) task.

When i use the `tortoisesvn` `status` on the command prompt in `windows 7` in the `basedir` of my repo, i get the following:

```
M  Build\build.xml
M  Build\otherStuff.txt
```

But when i use [svnant's](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html) [status](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#status) task i get:

```
svn.status.textStatusProperty = normal
svn.status.propStatusProperty = normal
```

I would expect it to return this:

```
svn.status.textStatusProperty = modified
svn.status.propStatusProperty = modified
```

---

When i go into the `Build` directory and do the same thing i get the following with `tortoisesvn`:

```
M  build.xml
M  otherStuff.txt
```

And the following with [svnant's](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html) [status](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#status) task:

```
svn.status.textStatusProperty = unversioned
svn.status.propStatusProperty = non-svn
```

That is really strange, because the `Build` directory is definitely versioned.

---

What is going on? What am i doing wrong?

**I am trying to find a quick way to check for modifications in my local copy of the svn repo. I know about the [wcversion](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#wcversion), but that task takes too long to execute. I was hoping to use something else that is much quicker.**

---

My code for the scenarios, the only thing that changes between the scenarios is the `path="${basedir}"`. It changes to point to the `basedir` or the `Build` directory. The `basedir` is my repo base.

```
    <svnSetting
    svnkit="false"
    javahl="false"
    id="svn.settings"/>

    <svn refid="svn.settings">  
        <status 
            path="${basedir}"
            textStatusProperty="testStatus.textStatus" 
            propStatusProperty="testStatus.propStatus" 
        />
    </svn>

    <echo>svn.status.textStatusProperty = ${testStatus.textStatus}</echo>
    <echo>svn.status.propStatusProperty = ${testStatus.propStatus}</echo></echo>
```

Comment: Since your svnant is using the native svn client, I recommend you to give svnkit (pure java implement of svn) a try.

Comment: I suspect somehow it wants the path to be a path to each individual versioned file or directory. So there doesn't seem to be a way to obtain status with svnant the way you can do it with "svn status" from command line.